# Formula to search data in 1 column and from data in 2nd column and display data of 2nd column

Tags: excel

I have two columns. Each cell in column A contains a full sentences and each cell in column B contains a word or phrase. I would like to check if the contents of any cell in column B appears in each cell in column A and get the word or phrase of the cell/cells of Column B that appear in Column A.

```
Column A      Column B     Search Result
Twenty One    Twenty       Twenty, One
Five Boxes    Ten       
Ten Words     Thirty       Ten
Twenty Pens   One          Twenty
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a matrix (array) formula to achieve this. Please enter the following formula into cell `C2` (assuming your table starts at `A1`):

```
=LEFT(CONCAT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2:$B$5;A2))=TRUE;$B$2:$B$5&", ";""));MAX(LEN(CONCAT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2:$B$5;A2))=TRUE;$B$2:$B$5&", ";"")))-2;0))
```

**Please make sure you press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` after pasting the formula into the cell!** This combination says to the Excel that you are using a matrix formula. If you press `Enter` only the formula will not work properly. Then you can copy the formula into cells below in a standard way. If you want to input more data you need to expand range `$B$2:$B$5`.

You can check my [example sheet here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AvP6NwTpIPzsmMEJDF-fOUC6-0vbpg). You can also read more about matrix formulas [in Microsoft documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7).

**Edit #1**
There is a different list separator in the US locale. If you use US locale please try this formula:

```
=LEFT(CONCAT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2:$B$5,A2))=TRUE,$B$2:$B$5&", ","")),MAX(LEN(CONCAT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2:$B$5,A2))=TRUE,$B$2:$B$5&", ","")))-2,0))
```

Please keep in mind to use `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` after entering the formula.

Comment: It did not work. Highlights the $B$5 part in the code.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the problem. Did you try to download my example sheet? You can see a working example in it.

Comment: Maybe you have a comma as a parameter separator in your Office. Please try to replace `;` by `,` in your Excel file.

Comment: Did this fix help?